# Export SQL XML field to grid

Tags: sql, sqlxml

I am working with a table that has an XML field.  This is the XML data as it appears in the field (it is much larger, I cut it for brevity), but each entry still has the 3 basic attributes: label, value, and qty.

```
<CountLog>
  <CountEntry label="distance_range" value="00_09" qty="166" />
  <CountEntry label="distance_range" value="10_19" qty="186" />
  <CountEntry label="distance_range" value="20_29" qty="166" />
  <CountEntry label="distance_range" value="30_39" qty="147" />
  <CountEntry label="distance_range" value="40_49" qty="4" />
</CountLog>
```

My question, how can I pull out the quoted values for each CountEntry?  I have tried several things that have give me little to no results.

Mark

Comment: Please tag with the actual RDBMS (product and version) and please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I did not see that question before.